# Inherit a generic class from another generic class

Tags: c#-4.0, generics

Here is my class hierarchy

```
BaseEntityCRUDGridViewModel :     BaseGenericViewModel
```

{
}

```
public class BaseGenericTests<ST> : SilverlightTest 
where ST : BaseGenericViewModel
```

How can I do the following

```
public class BaseEntityCRUDGridTests<T> : BaseGenericTests<T> 
where T : BaseEntityCRUDGridViewModel
```

It is giving me the following error

```
Error   5   The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'ST' in 
the generic type or method 'Commons.UnitTests.BaseGenericTests<ST>'. 
There is no implicit reference conversion from 'T' 
to 'ViewModels.BaseGenericViewModel'.
```

path\BaseNavigationTests.cs 23  27  Commons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest refactoring in such a way that both ViewModel classes implement the same interface. Then you can put the interface requirement on the generic base class, and you can do:

```
public class SubGenericTest<T> : BaseGenericTest<T> where T:IGenericVewModel, SubViewModel
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. Yup, it work fine there was some other effect that cause this error to came up.